# Multiple relationship between tables in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.4

I have 3 tables (**items**, **category_questions_mapping** and **category_questions**)  in mysql database in which I have the following columns:

**items table has following columns:**

```
item_id, uuid, radius, category_id
```

**category_questions_mapping has following columns:**

```
category_id, category_question_id
```

**category_questions has following columns:**

```
category_question_id, data
```

I have created the model for the **items** table which is **Items.php** in which I have created the following method:

```
public function category_questions() {
            return $this->hasOne('App\CategoryQuestionsMapping','category_id','category_id');
        }
```

The above method is basically a relationship between **category_id of the items table** with the **category_id of category_question_mappings table**

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I should make in the above method so that I am able to pull **data column value** from **category_questions table**. Is there any we can make a relationship in the above method so that it can pull the data column ?

The above method will be used in the controller for display.

Answer (score 1):

To acess the category_question table columns you must define the relationship on the category_question_mapping model too, like:

```
public function category_questions() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\CategoryQuestions','category_question_id','category_question_id');
}
```

then acess the field you want like `$items->category_questions_mapping->category_questions->data`.

By the way, I'd recommend naming the first relationship you showed like category_questions_mapping() as it is linking with the category_questions_mapping table.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change only the `category_questions` method to solve the problem. But you can make 2 relations in 2 models and query `data` through 2 relations.

```
// App\Item
public function category_questions_mapping() {
    return $this->hasOne(CategoryQuestionsMapping::class, 'category_id', 'category_id');
}

// App\CategoryQuestionsMapping
public function category_question() {
    return $this->hasOne(CategoryQuestion::class, 'category_question_id', 'category_question_id');
}

// Somewhere else

// Get data:
$data = $item->category_questions_mapping->category_question->data;

// Find by data:
$items = \App\Item
    ::whereHas('category_questions_mapping.category_question', function ($query) {
        $query->where('data', 'foo');
    })
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your relationship use like this :

```
public function category_questions()  {   
   return $this->belongsToMany('App\CategoryQuestions','category_questions_mapping','category_id', 'category_question_id);
}
```